# Swift Dictionaries with enum as Identifier not auto completing in completion block

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have a function that returns a completion. The completion has as in parameter a custom class with a dictionary that uses an enum as an identifier.

The problem I am facing is that Xcode does not recognises the type of the variable and does not auto complete when I use it inside of completion block.

My code looks like that

Function

```
func testFunc (completion:(PrxServiceResponseCallback) ->()){
    let responseCallback = PrxServiceResponseCallback()
    completion(responseCallback)
}
```

Class

```
class PrxServiceResponseCallback:NSObject{

    var success = false
    var resultCode:Int32 = 0

    var response:[PrxResponseAttributes:Any] = [PrxResponseAttributes:Any]()

}

enum PrxResponseAttributes{

    case sourceProtocolInfoArray
    case sinkProtocolInfoArray
    case connectionIDsArray
    case connectionInfo

}
```

Calling the function

```
testFunc { (testResonse) in
    testResonse.response[.]//Not Auto completing
}
```

The whole idea of making a dictionary with an enum as identifier was to make easier which attributes the dictionary returns but, If I can't auto complete, the idea is more pointless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode doesn't give you autocomplete doesn't mean that your code doesn't compile. It just means that Xcode is too stupid to figure things out. I have encountered such situations many times before. It seems to always happen inside closures.

You can just ignore the fact that no autocomplete shows up and type the case name yourself:

```
testResonse.response[.sourceProtocolInfoArray]
```

It will compile.

You can also consider creating a struct instead of storing the values in a dictionary. Here's a sample struct (I guessed the types):

```
struct Response {
    let sourceProtocolInfo: [String]
    let sinkProtocolInfo: [String]
    let connectionIDs: [Int]
    let connectionInfo: String
}
```

Comment: I see... I was using an enum because the callback class is reused 50 times so far along different functions and the idea of the dictionary was to send values identified because the each function returns different values.

Answer (score 1):

If you use   `var response:[UIColor:Any] = [UIColor:Any]()` 
it is still not giving auto complete so it is not your issue and you can not do much on it .

If you need auto complete then use  `PrxResponseAttributes` with . (dot)

you can do it  like

```
testResonse.response[PrxResponseAttributes.sourceProtocolInfoArray]
```

**EDIT**

Note: It is only happening with implemented closure if you add one property in your  `PrxServiceResponseCallback` class like

```
 var anyValue:Any? {
    return response[.connectionInfo] // it is showing completion 
}
```

Comment: PrxResponseAttributes. with the dot it was the thing i wanted to avoid...

Comment: @ReimondHill I understand but It is not in your control :( So you have no other option left please also check edit

Comment: @ReimondHill You can use struct instead a better way then dictionary

Comment: struct instead of dictionary? How can I do that?

Comment: create struct with your required property and use as  `response:yourStruct`

Comment: oh I am going to try. Thank you